# error al registrar por metodo get en volley, php, android

Tags: php, android, volley, singleton

Estoy empezando a incursionar en la programación android, tengo algunos conocimientos en otros lenguajes.

Tengo el siguiente problema al momento de darle en registrar muestra el siente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro el código php en el cual si realizo la pruebas me muestra los bien los mensajes cada if.

```
  <?php
$hostname_localhost="localhost";
$database_localhost="bdprueba";
$username_localhost="root";
$password_localhost="";

$json=array();
if(isset($_GET['nombre']) && isset($_GET['cedula']) )
{
        $nombre=$_GET['nombre'];
        $cedula=$_GET['cedula'];

        $conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

        if(!empty($nombre) && !empty($cedula))
            {
                $sql="SELECT  cedula FROM tregistro WHERE  cedula='$cedula' ";  
                $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
                {   
                    print json_encode( array(
                'estado' => '1',
                'mensaje1' => 'El usuario con Cedula :'))."<br>";
                    echo json_encode($json);
                    mysqli_close($conexion);
                }
                else
                {   
                    $query="INSERT INTO tregistro (nombre, cedula) VALUES ('$nombre','$cedula')";
                    $insert=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
                    if($insert)
                    {
                        print json_encode( array(
                            'estado' => '2',
                            'mensaje2' => 'Registro agregado correctamente'));
                        $json['2']="El usuario se guardo con exito";
                    }else
                    {
                        $json['3']='No se pudo crear la Cuenta';        
                        print json_encode( array(
                            'estado' => '3',
                            'mensaje3' => 'Todos los campos son obligatorios'));*
                    }

                    echo json_encode($json);
                    mysqli_close($conexion);
                }               
        }
        else
        {
            $json['4']='Todos los campos son Obligatorios';
                echo json_encode($json);
                mysqli_close($conexion);
        }
}
?>
```

La imagen de la ventana anterior viene desde una activity y manda a llamar 
al fragment llamado Registrarfragment muestro el código

```
package com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.MainActivity;
import com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.R;
import com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.entidades.VolleySingleton;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link RegistrarFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link RegistrarFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class RegistrarFragment extends Fragment  {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    EditText et_idUsuario,et_idCedula;
    Button btn_Registrarse;

    //PERMITE HACER LA CONEXION CON EL SERVIDOR
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    StringRequest stringRequest;



    public RegistrarFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment RegistrarFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static RegistrarFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        RegistrarFragment fragment = new RegistrarFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registrar, container, false);

        et_idUsuario=vista.findViewById(R.id.idUsuario);
        et_idCedula=vista.findViewById(R.id.idCedula);

        btn_Registrarse=vista.findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrarse);

        //requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        btn_Registrarse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                guardarMeta();
            }
        });
        return vista;

    }
    private void guardarMeta() {
        String ip=getString(R.string.ip);
        String url=ip+"/bd/registrar.php?";

            // Obtener valores actuales de los controles
          final String nombre = et_idUsuario.getText().toString();
        final String cedula = et_idCedula.getText().toString();

     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();// Mapeo previo

        map.put("nombre", nombre);
        map.put("cedula", cedula);

         //Crear nuevo objeto Json basado en el mapa
        JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(map);

            // Actualizar datos en el servidor
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).
            addToRequestQueue(
                new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,jobject,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // Procesar la respuesta del servidor
                    procesarRespuesta(response);

                    Log.e ( "response", "" + response );
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Respuesta="+response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error Volley"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
                ) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                        return headers;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/json; charset=utf-8" + getParamsEncoding();
                    }
                }




                );
        }


    private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {

        try {
            // Obtener estado
            String estado = response.getString("estado");
            // Obtener mensaje
            //String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");

            switch (estado) {
                case "1":
                    // Mostrar mensaje
                    String mensaje1 = response.getString("mensaje1");
                    Toast.makeText( getActivity(),"MESNAJE1 "+mensaje1.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Enviar código de éxito
                    Log.e ( "response", "" + response );
                    //getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_OK);
                    // Terminar actividad
                    //getActivity().finish();
                    break;

                case "2":
                    // Mostrar mensaje
                    String mensaje2 = response.getString("mensaje2");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"MESNAJE2 "+mensaje2.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e ( "response", "" + response );
                    // Enviar código de falla
                    //getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED);
                    // Terminar actividad
                    //getActivity().finish();
                    break;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public boolean camposVacios() {
        String titulo = et_idUsuario.getText().toString();
        String descripcion = et_idCedula.getText().toString();

        return (titulo.isEmpty() || descripcion.isEmpty());
    }
    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
        public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

EL SINGLETON

```
package com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.entidades;

import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Created by Administrador on 10/02/2019.
 */

public class VolleySingleton {

    private static VolleySingleton intanciaVolley;
    private RequestQueue request;
    private static Context contexto;


    //CONSTRUCTOR
    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        contexto= context;
        request= getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized VolleySingleton getIntanciaVolley(Context context) {
        if (intanciaVolley==null){
            intanciaVolley=new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return intanciaVolley;
    }

    private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if(request == null){
            request= Volley.newRequestQueue(contexto.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return request;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue (Request<T> request){
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
}
```

EL ADAPTADOR USUARIO

```
package com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.adaptadores;

/**
 * Created by Administrador on 30/01/2019.
 */

public class Usuario {
    private Integer idtregistro;
    private String nombre;
    private String cedula;

    public Integer getIdtregistro() {
        return idtregistro;
    }

    public void setIdtregistro(Integer idtregistro) {
        this.idtregistro = idtregistro;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En la parte del código de servidor (PHP) debes ser **estrictamente cuidadoso de sacar por pantalla un único objeto JSON válido y nada más**. En el código se ve que por una parte imprimes con `print` y por otra parte con `echo`. Si por ejemplo sacas dos veces un JSON Android no estará recibiendo un JSON válido. Para evitar confusiones controla el flujo del código y ofrece la salida una sola vez, fuera de todos los `if`. También sería bueno que pongas un encabezado con el content type y la codificación utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando hagas una petición Volley tu código de servidor tiene que ser coherente con lo que pongas aquí:

```
            new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,jobject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

Si en la petición se indica esto: `JSONObject`, significa que no puedes emitir desde el servidor **nada** que no sea un objeto JSON válido.

Es decir, tienes que controlar el flujo en el servidor, poniendo en cualquier circunstancia todas las salidas en un array (en este caso sería la variable `$json`, e imprimir ese array como JSON al final.

También, hay se indica que el método es POST, no GET. A veces son intercambiables en cuanto a la recuperación de datos, pero hay que ser coherentes.

Un ejemplo de código controlado sería este.

Por ejemplo aquí, otra cosa que he mejorado ha sido llamar a la clave `mensaje` en cualquier caso, en vez de `mensaje1`, `mensaje2`.... eso no tiene sentido, porque luego te obliga a hacer un `switch` en Android. Puedes tener una clave `mensaje` y recuperarla y mostrarla sin más. ¿Por qué? Porque siempre, pase lo que pase, habrá una clave llamada `mensaje` en el JSON.

Esta es mi propuesta:

#### PHP

```
<?php 
    $method=strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    if ( $method=="post" ) 
    {
        $nombre=( empty($_POST['nombre']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['nombre'];
        $cedula=( empty($_POST['cedula']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['cedula'];

        if( $nombre && $cedula )
        {

            $conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);
            $sql="SELECT cedula FROM tregistro WHERE  cedula='$cedula' ";
            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
            {   
                $json= array ('estado' => '1','mensaje' => 'El usuario con Cedula :');

            }
            else
            {
                $query="INSERT INTO tregistro (nombre, cedula) VALUES ('$nombre','$cedula')";
                $insert=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
                if($insert)
                {
                    $json=array("estado"=>'2', "mensaje"=> "El registro se agrego correctamente");
                }
                else
                {
                    $json=array("estado"=>'3', "mensaje"=> "Verificar usuario o contraseña");
                }
            }
                        mysqli_close($conexion);
        }   
        else
        {
            $json=array("estado"=>'4', "mensaje"=> "Todos los campos son obligatorios");
        }

    }
    else
    {
            $json=array("estado"=>'5', "mensaje"=> "Solamente método POST permitido");
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

> **NOTA:** Si estás enviando datos correctamente al servidor y lo que obtienes es el mensaje *`Todos los campos son obligatorios`*, puede
>   que necesites recuperar los encabezados con
>   `apache_request_headers()`. En alguna ocasión me ha sucedido eso con
>   `Volley` y el envío de datos desde Android al servidor.

---

#### Android

La respuesta se procesaría así:

```
private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        // Obtener estado
        String estado = response.getString("estado");
        // Obtener mensaje: UNA SOLA VEZ AQUÍ, PORQUE LA CLAVE SE LLAMA SIEMPRE mensaje
        String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");

        switch (estado) {
            case "1":
                // Mostrar mensaje
                Toast.makeText( getActivity(),"MESNAJE1 "+mensaje,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Enviar código de éxito
                Log.e ( "response", "" + response );
                //getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_OK);
                // Terminar actividad
                //getActivity().finish();
                break;

            case "2":
                // Mostrar mensaje
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"MESNAJE2 "+mensaje,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e ( "response", "" + response );
                // Enviar código de falla
                //getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED);
                // Terminar actividad
                //getActivity().finish();
                break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

No me meto con la lógica de tu `switch ... case`, eso es asunto tuyo. Pero en coherencia con tu código PHP, el JSON siempre tendrá una clave mensaje, por tanto, puedes recuperar ese contenido **fuera** del `switch`  y mostrarlo luego en los `case` si fuera necesario.

Ten en cuenta que un JSON es un objeto que sirve por lo general para tener datos organizados con una estructura más o menos común y uniforme. En este caso el JSON **siempre** tendrá dos claves: `error` y `mensaje`. Si tú en vez de eso cambias cada vez las claves por `mensaje1, mensaje2, mensaje3` estás en el fondo anulando una practicidad interesante del objeto y luego estarás obligado, para buscar el mensaje, a repetir código una y otra vez. Aquí hablamos de 3 ó 4 elementos en el JSON, pero ¿y si fueran 10,000 elementos?

Espero te sirva, y si no entiendes algo, puedes preguntar en comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Limpie un poco el codigo php 
con respecto al content type no sabria donde agregarlo
pero si tengo uno agregado en el codigo android

```
$json=array();
if(isset($_GET['nombre']) && isset($_GET['cedula']) )
{

        $nombre=$_GET['nombre'];
        $cedula=$_GET['cedula'];

        $conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

        if(!empty($nombre) && !empty($cedula))
            {
                $sql="SELECT cedula FROM tregistro WHERE  cedula='$cedula' ";
                $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                //echo "AQUI=",$sql;
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
                {   
                    //$json['1']='El usuario con Cedula :' .$cedula. ' ya existe';
print json_encode( array('estado' => '1',
                'mensaje1' => 'El usuario con Cedula :'))."<br>";

                }
                else
                {
                    $query="INSERT INTO tregistro (nombre, cedula) VALUES ('$nombre','$cedula')";
                    $insert=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

                    if($insert)
                    {
                        echo "El registro se agrego correctamente";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Verificar usuario o contraseña";
                    }

                }
                echo json_encode($json);
                mysqli_close($conexion);
            }   
        else
        {
            echo "todos los campos son obligatorios";
        }
}
else
{
    echo  "no viee por metodo ";
}

?>
```

despues de haber modificado un poco el codigo php me muestra elsiguietne mensaje aparentemente no puede convertir una cadena string en JSONOBJET.
LO que no se es donde implementar el codigo para la solucion sin en 
webservices o en android. talves me hechan una mano. Saludos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esta es una respuesta a tu pregunta?

Comment: Que no te va a funcionar así. Lee mi comentario a tu pregunta y si no entiendes lo que digo, replica, pide aclaraciones. ¿Ves esto en tu petición Volley: `new Response.Listener<JSONObject>` ? Eso significa que **obligatoriamente** tu código PHP debe devolver **únicamente** un `JSONObject` válido. Ante una petición así, no puedes jamas tener código como este: `echo "todos los campos son obligatorios";` porque eso, que se imprime por pantalla, **daña el JSON, no lo hace válido**. Tienes que controlar el código PHP e imprimir un JSON sí o sí, porque es lo que Volley espera.

Comment: En ese sentido tu código PHP es un descontrol total, por un lado sacas cosas con `echo`, por otro lado sacas cosas con `json_encode`. Ese código tiene que ser controlado estrictamente. Para todo el código puedes usar un array, supongamos que se llamará: `$mOutput`. Asignas a esa variable **cualquier salida** que produzca el código.

Comment: te agradesco por tomarte el tiempo y compartir tus conocimientos, tomare en cuenta todos las sugerencias. aora pondre la mano en el codigo para realizar los cambios.

Comment: Referente a tu nota pues talves logras echarme una mano nuevamente
 intente aplicar el apache_request_headers(), no logre hacerlo bien.
mas que todo orientarme...

Answer (score 0):

A. Cedano, en el codigo php hice un cambio en una de las condiciones

```
antes 'if($nombre && $cedula)' 
ahora 'if( (!empty($_POST['nombre'])) && (!empty($_POST['cedula'])))'
```

tambien en las variables

```
antes ' $nombre=(($_POST['nombre'])) ? NULL : $_POST['nombre'];
    $cedula=(($_POST['cedula'])) ? NULL : $_POST['cedula'];' 

ahora ' $nombre=(empty($_POST['nombre'])) ? NULL : $_POST['nombre'];
    $cedula=(empty($_POST['cedula'])) ? NULL : $_POST['cedula'];'
```

con estos cambio haciendo prueba con un formulaio html por metodo POST muestra todos los mensaje tal cual condicion if le corresponde.

pero aun desde el android me sigue mostrndo el ***mensaje que todos los campo son abligatorio***  talves puedas ayudar que estoy aciendo mal y como poder solucionarlo. grcias

Comment: Por favor no uses la zona de respuestas para añadir información sobre la pregunta. Puedes hacer ediciones la propia pregunta para eso. Esta área es sólo para respuestas. Es importante que comprendas cómo funciona el sitio, para no armar lío en la pregunta (esto no funciona como un foro). En cuanto a los errores que dices, el código que te muestro es correcto, prueba como te indico ahí y si hay algún error escribe un comentario debajo de mi respuesta. Si escribes en otra parte no seré notificado de que has escrito.

Comment: Buenas noches _Cedano_. te comento que tengo siertos incovenientes con el codigo php. cuando lo ejecuto por el programa postman solo muestra *todos los campos son obligatorios* y si ejecuto la aplicacion en android muestra el mensaje **'Error Volleycom.android.volley.ParseError:org.json.JSONException:Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject'**.   la verdad y hecho al pie de la letra lo que as indicado con el codigo php y el codigo en android. cuando puedas me echas una mano. me orientas para poder resolver estos inconvenientes. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

ASI Q despues de intentar, y hacer pruebas y error la unica forma que me funciono fue por medio del Stringrequest.y en la url tuve que agregar los campos que se van a guardar en la base de datos de esta manera `String url=ip+"/bd/registro.php?nombre="+et_idUsuario.getText().toString()+"&cedula="+et_idCedula.getText().toString();`

```
private void guardarMeta () {
        String ip = getString(R.string.ip);
        String url=ip+"/bd/registro.php?nombre="+et_idUsuario.getText().toString()+"&cedula="+et_idCedula.getText().toString();

        final String nombre = et_idUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
        final String cedula = et_idCedula.getText().toString().trim();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                       // final String estado= response.toString();
                        //Log.i("Error",response.toString());
                        Log.i("IMPRIMIR_RESPONSE=",response.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.i("ERROR_VOLLEY=",error.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("nombre",nombre);
                params.put("cedula",cedula);
                Log.i("IMPRIMIR_VARIABLE_PARA=",params.toString());
                return params;
            }

        };

        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

el php que fue proporcionado por el colega A.Cedano

```
<?php
$json=array();
 $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
       $cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
 $method=strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
if ( $method=="post" ) 
{
    if(!empty( $nombre) && !empty($cedula))
   {     
        $conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

        $sql="SELECT cedula FROM tregistro WHERE cedula='$cedula' ";
            //echo "CONSULTA=",$sql;
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
            {   
                $json= array ('estado' => '1','mensaje' => 'El usuario con Cedula existe');
                //echo "1";
                   /* $json= array (
                    'estado'=> '1',
                    'nombre'=>$nombre,
                    'cedula'=>$cedula,
                   );
                $json['estado']='1';
                $json['resulta']=$data;*/
            }
        else
           {
                $query="INSERT INTO tregistro (nombre, cedula) VALUES ('$nombre' , '$cedula' )";

                $insert=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

            if($insert)
                {
                  $json=array("estado"=>'2', "mensaje"=> "El registro se agrego correctamente");
                }
                else
                {
                    $json=array("estado"=>'3', "mensaje"=> "Verificar usuario o contraseña");
                }
            }
                        mysqli_close($conexion);
        }   
        else
        {
             /*/$json= array (
                    'estado'=> '4',
                    'nombre'=>$nombre,
                    'cedula'=>$cedula,
                   );*/
            $json=array("estado"=>'4', "mensaje"=> "Todos los campos son obligatorios");
        }

    }
else
{
    $json=array("estado"=>'5', "mensaje"=> "Solamente método POST permitido");
}

  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    echo json_encode($json);

    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]