# Error en JSON al intentar leer URL

Tags: java, json, http

El error que me da es:

> Unexpected character `(<)` at position 0.

No entiendo muy bien el por que ya que la url es correcta, creo que es un fallo al intentar leer el contenido de la página y no la url pero no tengo mucha idea.

El error concreto me da en el metodo leer url, y cuando lo uso, en el `getAll`, gracias de antemano.

La pagina me lo devulve en el siguiente formato: `[{"Codigo":"979d7a78237fe607f2376d0acd097d24","Longitud":-3.6893698,"Descripcion":"Plaza de Colón","Latitud":40.4257046,"Disponibilidad":9,"IdServicio":"bicimad"}]`

El código es:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;


public class DBRemoteAccessServicioDAO {
    URL url1;
    URL url2;

    public DBRemoteAccessServicioDAO()  {
        //URL url1 = new URL ("http://localhost:8080/practica4/Gbici");
        //URL url2 = new URL ("http://localhost:8080/practica4/Bicimad");
        try {
            url1 = new URL ("http://localhost:8080/practica4/Gbici");
            url2 = new URL ("http://localhost:8080/practica4/Bicimad");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static JSONArray leerJSONurl(URL url) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj=null;

        try {
            obj=parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONArray jArray=(JSONArray) obj;
        return jArray;
    }

    public void getAll(){
        List<Servicio> lista = new ArrayList<Servicio>();
        for(Object aux1: leerJSONurl(url2)) {
            String idServicio=(String) ((JSONObject)aux1).get("IdServicio");
            System.out.print(idServicio);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: El unexpected character parece el inicio de un tag, si es así no te está llegando un json. Pueden ser muchos motivos como una página default de 404 not found. Te sugiero usar postman para verificar lo que te llega desde la url y en todo caso actualizá la pregunta con lo que encontraste.

Comment: la pagina en si funciona y me devuelve en este formato [las cosas de la base de datos], y esta activa , ya que puedo acceder a ella desde eclipse

Comment: Podes agregar lo que devuelve la pagina a la pregunta (editando la pregunta) para ver como esta formateado el json.

Comment: Editada ya la pregunta

Comment: Si lo estás viendo en el navegador, si hacés boton derecho "ver código fuente", ves exactamente lo mismo o hay algún tag como <html>?

Comment: Aparece esto: <html><head><title>GBICI</title></head><body>
<h1>[{"Codigo":"4c89d17973694d65326bc1b6cf3effb4","Longitud":-3.727,"Descripcion":"16  R.LAS MARGARITAS","Latitud":40.322902,"Disponibilidad":6,"IdServicio":"gbici"}]</h1>

Comment: Este problema se debe a que el servidor no está devolviendo json, está devolviendo html. El servidor corre en tu máquina por lo que veo en la url. Cómo estás generando la respuesta?

Comment: Pienso lo mismo que @Juan , por el tipo de error se ve que retornas HTML mezclado con JSON, seria bueno ver el código del método que retorna los datos para determinar la causa o extraer el json dentro de el tag <h1> antes de procesarlo que no seria lo recomendado.

Comment: El código de servidor que genera el JSON tiene que estar muy pero muy controlado, y **no debe sacar por pantalla nada más que un JSON válido**, con que el código imprima `echo "";` o tenga un espacio en blanco o un bom, ya hace que la respuesta sea inválida. Así de delicadas son este tipo de respuestas. Generalmente para esto se suele usar header incluso, poniendo el datatype y el charset, para que la codificación tampoco te estropee el JSON. (Ver p. ejemplo [esta respuesta en el apartado PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/236892/29967), se imprime el JSON únicamente al final con un header).

Comment: Buenas,  he seguido intentando, y he descubierto que el error me da al parsear a json, alguna idea?